# One liner to chunk Ruby objects into sub arrays based on Date/Timeframe?

Tags: ruby, group-by

Say I have 1200 ActiveRecord objects with a `created_at` attribute, and 100 were created each month for a year.  What's the one liner ruby way to iterate through the records and chunk them by month?

```
[record_a, record_b, record_c, ...].group_by(&:month) do |month, records_for_the_month|
  records_for_the_month.each ...
end
```

... assuming I don't have a `month` method/attribute, and I might want to chunk by any arbitrary time frame (4 weeks, quarter year, season, weeks, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
Foo.all.group_by{|v| v.created_at.beginning_of_month }.values
```

Will return an array of arrays of records.